# How to validate if at-least one of the checkbox field is selected and display the error message

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a dynamic forms with a checkbox and a input text box. I wanted to validate if at-least one of the checkbox field is selected.

I have defined the form array in this way:

```
  public questionForm: FormGroup;

  public answer: Array<{ id: number; option: string; isAnswer: boolean }> = [];
    
  ngOnInit() {
    this.questionForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      label: ['', Validators.required],
      answers: this._formBuilder.array([]),
    });
    this.addOption();
  }

  addOption() {
    const fa = this.questionForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
    fa.push(
      this._formBuilder.group({
        id: [],
        option: ['', Validators.required],
        isAnswer: [false],
      })
    );
  }
```

I have implemented the html in the following way:

```
<form
  [formGroup]="questionForm"
  (submit)="onSubmit(questionForm)"
  novalidate
  [ngClass]="!formSubmitAttempt ? 'need-validation' : 'was-validated'"
>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row rowSpacing">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>
              <label class="formLabelStyles">Label</label
              ><span class="reqField">*</span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                formControlName="label"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Question..?"
                required
                [ngClass]="{
                  'is-invalid': formSubmitAttempt && f.label.errors
                }"
              />
              <div
                *ngIf="formSubmitAttempt && f.label.errors"
                class="invalid-feedback"
              >
                <div *ngIf="f.label.errors.required">
                  Question label is required
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="container mt-3">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Answer?</th>
                <th scope="col">Option</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody formArrayName="answers">
              <tr
                *ngFor="
                  let answer of questionForm.get('answers')['controls'];
                  let i = index
                "
                [formGroupName]="i"
              >
                <td class="align-middle">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input
                      class="form-check-input"
                      type="checkbox"
                      formControlName="isAnswer"
                    />
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                  <input
                    class="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    [ngClass]="{
                      'is-invalid':
                        formSubmitAttempt && answer.get('option').errors
                    }"
                    placeholder="Answer {{ i + 1 }}"
                    formControlName="option"
                    required
                  />
                  <div
                    *ngIf="formSubmitAttempt && answer.get('option').errors"
                    class="invalid-feedback"
                  >
                    <div *ngIf="answer.get('option').errors.required">
                      Option is required
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <div
              class="invalid-feedback"
              *ngIf="
                questionForm.controls['answers'].errors &&
                questionForm.controls['answers'].errors.required
              "
            >
              At least one checkbox is required to check
            </div>
          </table>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" (click)="addOption()" class="btn btn-primary">
              Add New Option
            </button>

            <button
              type="button"
              (click)="onSubmit($event)"
              class="btn btn-danger"
            >
              Save Question
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <pre>{{ questionForm.value | json }}</pre>
      <div>form valid: {{ questionForm?.valid }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I wanted to validate if at-least one of the checkbox field is selected and display the error message. For the checkbox required.

How can I do that? I am stuck on how to add the validation rules as at least one of the `isAnswer` field is checked in the form array.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mq4lf3)

Answer (score 0):

I would create custom validator for that, like below

```js
export function MinOneAnswer(formArray: FormArray) {
  const isOneSelected = formArray.controls.filter(x => x.value.isAnswer).length;
  if (!isOneSelected) {
    return { minOneAnswerNotSelected: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

and use it like this

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.questionForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    label: ['', Validators.required],
    answers: this._formBuilder.array([], MinOneAnswer),
  });
}
```